# What is this pipe coming from the basement wall?

Tags: water, walls, pipe

Trying to figure out what this pipe is for coming out of our basement wall. House was built around 1980. We purchased about 4 years ago. Home has well and septic. Well pump and pressure tank is nearby.

This pipe has never had anything connected to it since we purchased the home. When it rains, water drains out of the lower pipe. Last night it rained about 2” and filled the ice cream pail.

The upper pipe remains bone dry. I pushed a rod in the top pipe around 30” and didn’t feel a ridge or anything.

Trying to figure out what it is, where it may go and can I cap both the upper and lower pipes and let it fill with water so it stops draining into the house?

Any thoughts?

Thanks everyone
Joe

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you try digging on the opposite side of the wall to see if you can find it?

Comment: Haven’t yet. It ‘s about 6’ below the outside surface.

Comment: could be a outlet and  jet for connecting to a jet pump in a well.

Comment: connect an air compressor to the lower pipe ... turn air on slightly so that it makes a hissing sound ... go to the well and listen for hissing

Comment: Plan to try the compressor on it tomorrow. Any thoughts though if it was connected to the well, why when it rains, it leaks? It’s the only time anything comes out of it. Otherwise, both pipes are bone dry.

Comment: I had a similar issue. The house I bought had a well that was disconnected. When it rained the old pipe from the well would drip water into the crawl space. It would take a while after a rain storm before the rain water would seep through the ground to the open pipe and then start dripping. I capped it off and have had no issues.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be abandoned hard pipe for your well. I used to run hard pipe to the well head and convert to poly at the cap so the jet or foot can be pulled up. Someone may have changed to submersible as I did in my current home because submersible pumps are much more efficient, when doing this they may have abandoned the original plumbing as it was easier than removal. I would cap them so they don’t drip. They can be cut off and plugged but if they don’t bother you you may want to leave them in place just capped.

Comment: Ed, thanks much! I will cap them off and go from there!